# Can I observe when a UIViewController changes interfaceOrientation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

If I have a pointer to a UIViewController, can I be notified when it changes interfaceOrientation without modifying the code of the controller?

Is my best bet to detect changes in device orientation and then see if the UIViewController will/has rotate(d)?

Comment: not sure if the question is still actual, but you can use objc method swizzling to add your own code into the `UIViewController`'s code. This should look like exchanging `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` with your own implementation which has a call to your orientation changed handler method and a call to original implementation

Comment: @medvedNick That seems reasonable. I could call my delegate then call the original implementation. I might be a little worried about potential side effects.

Answer (score 16):

You can use NSNotificationCenter :

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self // put here the view controller which has to be notified
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{  
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    //do stuff
    NSLog(@"Orientation changed");          
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I wasn't clear. I want to know the apparent orientation of a ViewController rather than the device. In other words, my object wants to observe a view controller to see its orientation, which may be different from the device's and may not change when the device changes orientation. This answer is part of what I was implying in the second part of my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method on your UIViewController and then reposition any UIViews (or any other code) for landscape or portrait. E.g.

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
  if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    // change positions etc of any UIViews for Landscape
  } else {
    // change position etc for Portait
  }

  // forward the rotation to any child view controllers if required
  [self.rootViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would mean changing the code of the UIViewController. Here I only have a pointer to it and want to observe its behavior. What'd I'd really like to do is be notified when "interfaceOrientation" returns a different value.

Comment: NB: This is deprecated in iOS 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238620/ios-8-rotation-methods-deprecation-backwards-compatibility