# UIViewController device rotation delegate methods are not getting called in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8

I have been working an iOS 7 app to make it compatible for ios 8 (beta 5). In this application, `UIViewController` (`vc1`) presents another `UIViewController` (`vc2`). `vc1` supports both Portrait and Landscape orientations; `vc2` supports only Portrait orientation. When `vc2` is presented, it asks `vc1`: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and this returns `YES`.

In iOS8 (Beta 5) `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` are not getting called as well as the new iOS 8 API method `viewWillTransitionToSize`. But, this works fine in iOS7.

I know `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` are deprecated in iOS 8, but even iOS 8 delegate methods are not getting called. Every time when launched `vc2` from `vc1` always screens loads in portrait mode only even though I mentioned supported interface orientation as landscape left.

Any ideas... is it a bug in iOS8?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238620/ios-8-rotation-methods-deprecation-backwards-compatibility

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935006/ios8-interface-rotation-methods-not-called

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't figure out your problem best but as soon I have a bunch of lines working fine with rotation in iOS 8.1 I will present them to you. They are just taken and a little bit of edited from the Apple API Reference.

Simply I put this in every VC and i just edit the code when needed. For example I have an app that have initial view controller in portrait and then VC changes ( segue is done ) to a LandscapeVC with different features.
This is the portrait view methods leading to a rotation in LandscapeView.

```
bool isShowingLandscapeView = false;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLandscape" sender:self];
    }
```

I hope I made it simple for understanding. Don't hesitate to improve my answer, we all learn in this life !