# iOS8 how to understand interface orientation from UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate, transition-coordinator

I'm debugging a project that was working fine in iOS7.1, but does not lay out it's content properly in iOS 8.0. I've narrowed the issue down to this method:

```
 [self orientRootViewControllerForOrientation:rootViewController.interfaceOrientation];
```

**iOS8 no longer returns correct UIInterfaceOrientation** from `rootViewController.interfaceOrientation`, instead it returns "upside down".

Reading the documentation, I'm confronted with a cryptic message:

> Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: to make
>   interface-based adjustments.

Reading documentation on  UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, I don't see it having any properties. **How can I modify my method that expects an interface orientation to get it's orientation from  UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator?**

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are supposed now to layout your content based on the available size, no more on the rotation. Which results in big pains to support older rotation-based code.

The view controller transition coordinator provides a [UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) that has a rotation factor. This could give you the hint you need ?
This [blog post](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/08/06/ios8-day-by-day-day-14-rotation-deprecation) mentions this too.

You also have the usual device (`[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`) or status bar orientation.
In case you are working on iOS 6 rotation methods, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238620/ios-8-rotation-methods-deprecation-backwards-compatibility) has relevant informations too.