# Why IS viewWillRotateToInterfaceOrientation being called in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

All of the questions I can find relating to viewWillRotate and iOS8 ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25238620/1480518) for an example) explain how the `viewWill/DidRotateToInterfaceOrientation` methods have been deprecated and should NOT be called on iOS8. However, I'm observing that it IS being called, in an app built using XCode 6.1 and running on the iOS 8.1 simulator. What black magicks are afoot?

In fact, from the call stack it looks like it's being called from `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator`, which is... I mean it's nice of iOS8 to decide that it wants to pander to my out-of-date code, but I'd rather it didn't go deviating from the spec whenever it feels like, thank you very much.

Has anyone seen something like this before, and have any idea why it could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a method is deprecated that does not necessarily mean that the method will not be called. A feature can be deprecated because it has been superseded by some other functionality, and that may mean that it still works, just not reliably or in all cases.