# detecting wrong orientation in iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

Things are easy to handle if the user rotates the device (I handle the call of viewWillTransitionToSize), but the app has to know its initial orientation.

Until now, I have been using the status bar orientation and device        orientation

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))
{
//
}

if (INTERFACE_IS_PHONE && UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) ) { 
 //
}


UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (INTERFACE_IS_PHONE && UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) ) {
 //
 }
```

above methods showing wrong orientation ,any ?

Comment: Maybe this could help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26132456/1492173). Put `UIInterfaceOrientation fromOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];` as the first line in your `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Comment: I'd argue you don't need orientation really. Since iOS 8, size classes + view size gives you the information you need to layout your view correctly. Orientation is getting to be more and more irrelevant with modern UIKit.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneDubinin

Comment: Thanks for commenting @LeoNatan