# setStatusBarOrientation deprecated,how to change the device orientation in ios10

Tags: ios, orientation

In ios10 ,setStatusBarOrientation is deprecated. some snippet of the old project code can't work fine. So how to solve them? the following code will change the the viewcontroller as we want:

```
 float angle;
 CGRect rect;
//    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation;
    float fWidth = _viewController.view.bounds.size.width;
    float fHeight = _viewController.view.bounds.size.height;
    float fMaxValue = (fWidth > fHeight) ? fWidth : fHeight;
    float fMinValue = (fWidth > fHeight) ? fHeight : fWidth;

    if ((eScreenOrientation)ore == eScreenOrientation::Landscape) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
//            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
            angle = M_PI_2;
        } else {
//            orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            angle = -M_PI_2;
        }
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, fMaxValue, fMinValue);
    } else {
//        orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        angle = 0;
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, fMinValue, fMaxValue);
    }

//  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: orientation];
    _viewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    _viewController.view.bounds = rect;
    [_viewController resetViewSize];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to be believed that -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] has been deprecated to support the use of UITraitCollection and size classes.

Also from apple docs

@property(readonly, nonatomic) UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

// Explicit setting of the status bar orientation is more limited in iOS 6.0 and later.
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 9_0,
"Explicit setting of the status bar orientation is more limited in iOS 6.0 and later") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;

Seems you cannot use the above code for the same purpose.

May be this link helps you [Link to orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238620/ios-8-rotation-methods-deprecation-backwards-compatibility/26132456#26132456)